# Why does return RedirectToAction("/Index") work and RedirectToAction("Index)" not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

For a long time, I've had an action that returned

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Vendor");
```

and it worked as expected. At the completion of this function, my Index function was called.

However, lately it stopped working. That same line of code now directs the browser to the url `localhost:67676/Vendor/`, my `Index()` action is never called  and the page displays:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>
> The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

However, if i add a forward slash to the method parameters like

```
return RedirectToAction("/Index","Vendor");
```

Everything works as expected and the Index function is called.

Any idea why I need to use `"/Index"` now but `"Index"` worked before

Comment: Have you added a folder to your app named `Vendor`?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. Do you know why ("/Index") works but ("Index") doesn't?

Comment: Then I assume that means you do have a folder named `Vendor` (which is the problem - just rename it to something else and it will work fine). As the message is telling you, your url is redirecting to a folder, not a controller method.

Comment: I thought you meant in the Views folder. Turns out I actually do have a folder called Vendors in my project folder. Thanks man

Comment: I'll add an answer explaining the issue in detail a bit later.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that you have a folder in your app named `Vendor` and the url is trying to navigate to that folder rather than your `VendorController`. To solve the problem, rename the folder so that it does not match a controller name.

To understand what is happening behind the scenes,

`return RedirectToAction("Index","Vendor");` internally looks at your route definitions for a match, and it matches your default route which has `defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`. Because you pass `"Vendor"` as the controller, which does not match default, the first segment of the url becomes `Vendor`. And because your pass `"Index"` as the action, it matches the route, so no additional segment is added (its not required). The final url becomes `localhost:67676/Vendor` which matches your folder (hence the error).

When you used `return RedirectToAction("/Index","Vendor");`, your passing `"/Index"` which does not match the default action (`"/Index" != "Index"`) so it generates a 2nd segment in the url which now becomes `localhost:67676/Vendor/Index` which will hit the controller because you don't (and could not) have a folder named `"Vendor/Index"`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but I'm posting it under this thread because I ran into the same problem. If there is a folder with the same name as Controller in your project file, you are encountering this problem.
Example;
**VendorController -
Vendor (Folder Name)**
I encountered this problem because of the wrong path I wrote when I wanted to create a new folder to save an image file.
Be careful when creating "Server.MapPath".